# Validating a Number for long

Tags: actionscript, numbers

I have generated actionscript (AS3) beans from the Serverside(java).

Now some of the classes had (Long,long,double) which I had to convert into Number on the Actionscript side (as we dont have long ,double etc ) on AS3 side.

Now I have to validate Number on AS3 side to match type on Serverside .

Let take example I have a field

private long number ;

in java which is converted as

private number:Number ; on AS side

this will accept number as (Double Long etc) but we know that we cannot fit Double into long on java

so I am wondering is there anyway we can validate AS3 Number to be valid "Long" on Acrionscript side ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would hard code the ceiling for a 'long' and then compare against that when sending a value to the server. Like so:

```
var floatCeiling:Number = Math.pow(2, 63) - 1;

var testValue:Number = 1000000000000000000000000;

if(testValue >= floatCeiling) {
    //tell the server to cast this value to 'double' when it gets it
} else {
    //tell the server to cast this value to 'long' when it gets it
}
```

That might be a little hacky for some, but, hope it helps :)

Comment: Np :) After looking at it again - you'll need to catch large negative values too. Anyway, good luck with it!